# Сохранение значения input[type='file'] при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, файлы

Есть форма заполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отправляется форма POST запросом, и вот если неправильно указан логин например, то значения всех полей текстовых я сохраняю в сессию, и они сохраняются, дабы пользователь не вводил все по-новому.

А вот если загружен файл, как сохранить значение этого поля, чтобы не перезагружать файл по новому?...

Comment: @Cactus с помощью ajax я знаю как можно, а вот интересует вопрос, можно ли как-то так вставить в value tmp_path, или другим "фокусом"...

Comment: У вас случайно нету возможности обрезать фотографию перед загрузкой на сервер?

Comment: @Cactus такой функционал не предусмотрен у нас

Comment: Ну хорошо=) Извините, если что..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1.

Вы сохраняете файл на сервере при любом раскладе. При неверном заполнении вы показываете путь к выбранному файлу или превьюшку, чтобы показать что файл выбран. При повторном правильном вводе файл подхватывается с сервера.

Вариант 2.

Вместо файла на сервер идет base64, запоминается где-нибудь. При неверном заполнении форма парсит сохраненное значение base64 и показывает превью или путь к файлу.

Установить в поле type=file значение, насколько я знаю, нельзя.